# Error on uploading app to play console- "Upload failed The Android App Bundle was not signed ."

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

When I upload the signed bundle of the app to play store it gives an error-
"Upload failed
The Android App Bundle was not signed."

Comment: Hard to help if you don't say how you generated you AAB. Did you sign it? Do you use Android Studio? What have you tried?

Comment: @Bedanta Kakati: Did you solve it? I am experiencing the same problem. Could you please share the solution as an answer here..?

Comment: i also face this issue i add this line `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` in android > app> build.gradle > `{buildType{release{ signingConfig signingConfigs.release }}}`

Answer (score 51):

In my case, for the same issue, `debuggable` was `true` in the selected build type while generating build.

After setting it to `false`, the generated build started to get uploaded in Play Store. Play Store does not accept builds with `debuggable` on.

Comment: Although according to documentation it does allow you use debuggable APKS:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9303479
Guess bundles don't apply. Weird.

Comment: @AndroidDev Well, above link talks about internal app sharing. Which totally different than normal release tracks. Internal app sharing is a new feature introduced recently where developers can share even de-buggable App Bundle or APK builds with testers. It generates a unique link for each build uploaded which can be shared with others. I guess, it does not effect other release tracks with version codes.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on this for a while. Although my feeling is they could make the error more specific, it's currently very confusing.

Comment: @Muganwas I feel you. Google has to work on many error scenarios to show appropriate messages to the developers. On Play Store and in Android Studio as well.

Comment: Thanks! that was my issue

Comment: The error message is very irrelevant to the real problem, setting debuggable true giving error bundle was not signed, weird.

Answer (score 10):

In seems that `The Android App Bundle was not signed` (`Набор Android App Bundle не подписан`) error can be produced by some incompatible debug or testing-related options in `release` build type. In my case problem was solved by removing `testCoverageEnabled true` from `release` build type section.

Now these sections looks like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: Awesome! removing the `testCoverageEnabled true` fixed this for me. I added this while fixing sonar for my KMM android project. Never realised it will fail the Azure pipeline delivery of bundle.

Answer (score 1):

like said above, make debuggable be false , and also , when generating signed bundle , be sure you pressed the "export encrypted key for enrolling..." .